# How to emulate the ScriptingContext's "ASPTypeLibrary.Application" Object

Tags: iis, vb6, activex

I have been tasked with modifying some legacy ActiveX DLLs written in Visual Basic 6. One of the things I need to do is to emulate the "ScriptingContext" object, (so that we can support other mechanisms for running the DLLs other than IIS without having to re-write large chunks of the code).

Something that has been causing me some grief is the "ASPTypeLibrary.Application" object which has two very different ways to access its stored values, eg:

```
 .Application("KeyName")
```

or

```
 .Application.Value("KeyName")
```

How can I create my own VB6 class which supports both of these access mechanisms? I can do one or the other but not both?

(a simple code example would be great thanks, I'm not a VB6 programmer)

Comment: It is the exact same statement.  Value is simply the default property so it can be omitted.  I don't remember if VB6 supported the Default keyword.

Comment: So if I create a Class with a Property "Application" then .Application.Value("KeyName") will return the same value as .Application("KeyName")?

Comment: Just tested this and it doesn't work...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ummm... doesn't that make my question LESS clear now? Not many people would know what "ScriptingContext" is, but by qualifying it with "VB6's", this helps to clarify my request.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this, see the code snippet below taken from two classes, "clsContext" and "clsContextApp". The latter implements the ".Value" functionality and the former has the ".Application" property...

I have now discovered an even more difficult problem. The ScriptingContext's "ASPTypeLibrary.Request" object has **three** different ways to access its ".Request.QueryString" property:

.Request.QueryString("KeyName")
 or
.Request.QueryString.Value("KeyName")
 or
.Request.QueryString

The last method returns a string comprised of all the Key/Value pairs concatenated by "&" characters. I have no idea how to implement this?

```
' clsContext
Public ContextApp As clsContextApp


Public Property Get Application(Optional ByRef Key As Variant = Nothing) As Variant
 If (Key Is Nothing) Then
  Set Application = ContextApp
 Else
  If (Not ContextApp.p_Application.Exists(Key)) Then
   Application = ""
  Else
   Application = ContextApp.p_Application.Item(Key)
  End If
 End If
End Property

Public Property Let Application(ByRef Key As Variant, ByVal Value As Variant)
 If (VarType(Key) = vbString) Then
  If (VarType(Value) = vbString) Then
   If (Not ContextApp.p_Application.Exists(Key)) Then
    ContextApp.p_Application.Add Key, Value
   Else
    ContextApp.p_Application.Item(Key) = Value
   End If
  End If
 End If
End Property



' clContextApp
Public p_Application As Scripting.Dictionary


Public Property Get Value(Key As String) As String
 If (Not p_Application.Exists(Key)) Then
  Value = ""
 Else
  Value = p_Application.Item(Key)
 End If
End Property

Public Property Let Value(Key As String, Value As String)
 If (Not p_Application.Exists(Key)) Then
  p_Application.Add Key, Value
 Else
  p_Application.Item(Key) = Value
 End If
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I've managed to answer the additional question regarding ScriptingContext's "ASPTypeLibrary.Request" object which has **three** different ways to access its ".Request.QueryString" property.

I've included a code snippet below that is based on the code from my previous answer for the "ASPTypeLibrary.Application" object. If I add a new Property to the "clsContextApp" class and make it the **default property** for that class, then it will be called when the ".Application" property is called without any qualification eg:

MyString = Context.Application

Setting a particular property as the default property in VB6 is a little obscure, but I followed the directions I found [**here**](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VB/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/2005-07/msg00281.html).

```
' clsContextApp Default Property
Property Get Values(Optional ByVal Index As Integer = -1) As String  ' This is the Default Value for clsContextApp
Attribute Values.VB_UserMemId = 0
 Dim KeyName As String, Value As String

 Values = ""

 If (Index < 0) Then
  For Index = 0 To p_Application.Count - 1
   KeyName = p_Application.Keys(Index)
   Value = p_Application.Item(KeyName)
   If (Index > 1) Then
    Values = Values + "&"
   End If
   Values = Values + KeyName + "=" + Value
  Next Index
 Else
  If (Index < p_Application.Count) Then
   KeyName = p_Application.Keys(Index)
   Value = p_Application.Item(KeyName)
   Values = KeyName + "=" + Value
  End If
 End If
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a reference to Microsoft Active Server Pages Object Library, and to COM+ Services Type Library, and then using the object browser reveals some basic things you seem to be missing.

`GetObjectContext` is a global method in COMSVCSLib with no arguments used to retrieve the current ObjectContext as its return value.

`ObjectContext` is a Class.  It has a read-only *default property*, named Item that takes a String argument and is of type Variant.

Passing `"Application"` as an argument to `Item` returns the current instance of the Application Class.

`ScriptingContext` is a Class.  It is obsolete.

`Application` is another Class.  It has a *default property* named Value that takes a String argument and is of type Variant.

`Value` is a property of the Application Class and provides access to a read-write key/value pair store where keys are always Strings.  Since it is of type Variant you can store objects as well as simple values and arrays of various types.

None of this looks difficult to replicate in VB6.  The key/value store could be a Collection or Scripting.Dictionary.